# CDK Pipeline - Trigger Step Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I’m trying to add additional steps to a CDK pipeline. I have a CDK Pipeline which creates all my resources (including some Step Functions). Now I’d like to execute a step function once CDK has finished deploying. How would you tackle this?
I was looking for something like the addAction  method of a “regular” pipeline from the aws-codepipeline module.

Would you consider it the right approach to trigger this step function from cdk pipeline or would you recommend a separate “regular” CodePipeline which then can be triggered by e.g. EventBridge event?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Wave` construct with the `post` property to execute a step after a wave:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_pipelines.Wave.html#addwbrpoststeps

You can trigger it from a `CodeBuildStep`, but make sure you grant it the required rights.